# Angular 5.2 : Error Property does not exist on type component

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, .net-core, angular5

I have added the properties in Formbuilder.Group method as (**ts code**):

```
this.form = this.fb.group({          
        caseNumber: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(50), Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$')]],
        userName: ['', [Validators.required]],
```

Info Interface ts file :

```
   export interface Information {
    userName : string 
    caseNumber: string
}
```

I am asgining values to variables using patch value method as (**ts code**):

```
Info: Information;

         this.form.patchValue({
            caseNumber: this.Info.caseNumber,
            userName: this.jsonArrayvalues(this.Info.userName, this.dropdownListForUserName),
```

Also i have used these properties in **html** file as :

```
 <div class="form-group padding-top-bottom" [ngClass]="{'has-error': (form.get('userName').touched ||
                                              form.get('userName').dirty) &&
                                              !form.get('userName').valid }">
                                <label class="col-md-4" for="firstNameId"><span tooltip={{attributeNames.userNameTitle}} data-placement="right">Vendor Name</span></label>
                                <div class="col-md-7">
                                    <ng-select [items]="userName"
                                               multiple="true"
                                               [addTag]="true"
                                               bindLabel="itemName"
                                               (change)="onItemSelect($event,'user','userName')"
                                               formControlName="userName"
                                               [(ngModel)]="userName">
                                    </ng-select>
```

But When i run command **ng build --prod** i get following error:

> ERROR in src\app\components\new\new.component.html(161,48): : Property '**userName**' does not exist on type '**NewComponent**'.

Same works fine with command **ng build**

Comment: Error shows the issue with line 161, can you tell which line is at 168?

Comment: The error is located in your statement this.Info.userName. What is the type of the Info variable? It seems that typescript knows there is no field named userName inside it. You have an error with --prod because it does more checks than without (where you would see the error at runtime in the browser console).

Comment: You are using:
```
formControlName="userName"
[(ngModel)]="userName"
```
Leave just the formControlName

Comment: @Mic Info is a ts interface which contains properties to bind in patch value method

Comment: @SumitVekariya Line 161 is :  <ng-select [items]="userName"

Comment: @pokrishka what purpose it solves ?

Comment: Post the code of your component class definition. Most likely, you are missing a `userName` field so `[items]="userName"` cannot be resolved.

Comment: @Mic The userName is array only which is defined inside pacthvalue() method . Updated code above

Comment: Then that's the issue. With `[items]="userName"`you're telling the template to look for a variable named `userName` as a member of the component - and it does not exist.

Comment: @Mic but it only fails if i run command with --prod as option it works for ng build command. and it is referring to property under patchvalue method

Comment: No I don't think so. Post your full component Code to see better. The --prod thing is because it does more check than without, not that your code is correct.

Comment: @Mic I have solved it by creating properties inside ts file which are refereed in HTML file .(with same name and type referenced in patch value method). Thanks for your help. It helped

Comment: [items]="userName" has nothing to do with FormGroup or the properties inside it. Your FormGroup is for what the person "selected" or entered in the form. Your [items]="userName" is for all the available items BEFORE selection.

Comment: you should really create 2 properites. One array in your ts file called "allUsers : string[]" and another property in your formGroup called "selectedUsers".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ng-select [items]="userName"
...
</ng-select>
```

is expecting an array for the items property (which I don't see in your posted code).

By the way, you should probsbly call it "userNames" since it should be an array.

```
<ng-select [items]="userNames" //!!! array
...
</ng-select>
```